# Post Error, "Error converting value 'ID' to type" to

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I changed a relationship between my Job and CustomerEmployee Class, I am trying to make a Post and I am getting a error. Using a break point I see that the Id's are not making it back to the apiController. I have done some searching and I think it seems it might be a Json issue, not sure how to correct it. I have 6 Id's I am trying to Post but they are setup the same so I will show code for one of them

Error Message

```
$id: "1"
Message: "The request is invalid."
ModelState: {$id:2, newJob.CustomerEmployeePMId:[,…], newJob.CustomerEmployeeAdminId:[,…],…}
$id: "2"
newJob.CustomerEmployeeAccountantId: [,…]
0: "Error converting value 10 to type 'TexasExteriorSPA.Models.CustomerEmployee'. Path    'CustomerEmployeeAccountantId', line 1, position 150."
newJob.CustomerEmployeeAdminId: [,…]
newJob.CustomerEmployeePMId: [,…]
newJob.CustomerEmployeeSuperintendentId: [,…]
```

view

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="customer.CustomerEmployeeId as customer.CustomerEmployeeFirstName + ' ' + customer.CustomerEmployeeLastName for customer in customerEmployeeArray | filter:{CustomerEmployeeRole : 'Accountant', CustomerId : currentItem.CustomerId}  " ng-model="currentItem.CustomerEmployeeAccountantId">
     <option value="" selected="selected">Customer Acct</option>
</select>
```

Angular Controller

```
//Post New Job
$scope.submitJob = function () {
    var data = {
        JobId: $scope.JobId,
        CustomerEmployeeAdminId: $scope.currentItem.CustomerEmployeeAdminId
    }
    $http.post('/api/apiJob/PostNewJob', data).success(function (data, status, headers) {
        console.log(data);
                 $scope.openNewJobModal.then(function (m) {
                   m.modal('hide');
                 });
    });
};
```

WebApiConfig

```
 // Web API configuration and services
        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "JobApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "apiJob", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
```

apiController

```
  // POST api/<controller>
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostnewJob([FromBody]JobViewModel newJob)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var job = new Job();

            Mapper.CreateMap<JobViewModel, Job>();
            Mapper.Map(newJob, job);

            context.Jobs.Add(job);

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtRoute("JobApi", new { job.JobId }, job);
        }
    }
```

Job Class

```
 public class Job
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int64 JobId { get; set; }
    public CustomerEmployee CustomerEmployeeAccountantId { get; set; }
}
```

CustomerEmployee Class

```
public class CustomerEmployee
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerEmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmployeeFirstName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmployeeLastName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmployeeRole { get; set; }

    public Int64? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

}
```

Update, It looks like the Id is not making it out of the Angular Controller
[image: pic]
[image: pic2]

Comment: The property on your model `CustomerEmployeeAccountantId` is of type `CustomerEmployee`, i.e. it is an object not ad id. It looks like you are setting it to 10 in your Json, so the model binder is saying it cannot bind the value `10` to a property of type `CustomerEmployee`. You either need to send json that can be deserialise to a `CustomerEmployee` or change the property on your model to an int.

Comment: how would I deserialise it, i cannot change it to a int because I will lose my relationship

Comment: It would deserialise automatically, so long as the JSON posted was valid. That's the magic of the model binder.

Comment: in this case how do I Post valid JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I can see, I think that Florian has it right. Your code should probably be something like:

```
public class Job
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int64 JobId { get; set; }

    public int CustomerEmployeeAccountantId { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerEmployee CustomerEmployeeAccountant { get; set;}
}
```

Your object should have a reference to both the Key (CustomerEmployeeAccountantId) and the object (CustomerEmployeeAccountant). The reason your code is failing is that your DB link is between the Id's, hence the 10 that's trying to be assigned to the property. The "Id" property should be an int.

By adding the additional virtual property, you're telling Entity Framework "Hey, put the Id of the Foreign Key in the Id property and then go ahead and fill out CustomerEmployee object with the associated data based on the Foreign Key relationship."

Then, if you want to access the CustomerEmployeeAccountant data, it should be available in the JSON object returned by your API in a property marked CustomerEmployeeAccountant.

Just be careful. I've noticed that WebApi and EF don't always do so well with recursive objects, so I'd personally dump this data into a ViewModel before it's passed to the client. There are ways to turn it off/change the behaviour, but I'm huge fan of only returning exactly what you need to minimize bandwidth.

Also, just a personal preference, but it seems to be the direction that most of Microsoft's documentation is headed, is to favor long over int64. It's the same data type, but I've noticed the trend of using long for naming consistency. Int64 is technically correct though.

**UPDATE:**

Looking at your screenshots, trying changing your variable name from var data = {}; to var postData = {};. I can't see the rest of your code, but it looks like there are several variables named data. Could that be causing the conflict?

Comment: will try that in a sec. I am getting a error adding a migration. Sequence contains more than one element

Answer (score 1):

`"Error converting value 10 to type 'TexasExteriorSPA.Models.CustomerEmployee'` is the relevant line. It seems like you're passing the value `10` as `CustomerEmployeeAdminId`. C# now tries to convert your given object to an object of type `JobViewModel` and fails when it want's to convert `10` to `CustomerEmployee`. You could do something like this to fix it:

```
public class Job
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int64 JobId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerEmployeeAccountantId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that is how I have my relationship with the CustomerEmployee Class. If i change it to a 'int' it has no connection to it